# Updating global variables in listview (Android)

Tags: android, android-listview, global-variables, android-arrayadapter

I have an issue that I am trying to resolve. I have created a list with three items in it that also allows you to add images to the list by following this tutorial...

Here, in order, is what I did.
1. I began by creating a class called 'Item' to serve as a model for the list items.

```
public class Item
{
  public int Id;
  public String IconFile;
  public String Name;

  public Item(int id, String iconFile, String name
  {
     Id = id;
     IconFile = iconFile;
     Name = name;
  }
}
```

.2. I then created a class called 'Model' to provide an ArrayList for my items. However, instead of simply putting text in the list names I included global variables.

http://www.debugrelease.com/2013/06/24/android-listview-tutorial-with-images-and-text/

```
public class Model extends Globals
{
    public static ArrayList<Item> Items; 
    public static void LoadModel() 
    {
        Items = new ArrayList<Item>();
        Items.add(new Item(1, "temperature_icon.png", "Temperature/Humidity" + temperature + "°C / " + humidity + "%"));
        Items.add(new Item(2, "gas_icon.png", "LPG" + lpg +" ppm"));
        Items.add(new Item(3, "alcohol_icon.png", "Alcohol" + alcohol + " ppm"));
    }  

    public static Item GetbyId(int id)
    {
        for(Item item : Items) 
        {
            if (item.Id == id) 
            {
                return item;
            }
        }
        return null;
    } 
}
```

.3. (Extra step) I added a global class to have access to the global variables.

```
public abstract class Globals extends Activity
{
    static int temperature;
    static int humidity;
    static int lpg;
    static int alcohol;
}
```

.4. Add listview widget to main activity layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

.5. Add custom layout since I am displaying more than text.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:minHeight="64dp">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="97dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="66dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

.6. Create custom adapter to display data

```
public class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Context context;
    private final String[] Ids;
    private final int rowResourceId;

    public ItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, String[] objects) {

        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);

        this.context = context;
        this.Ids = objects;
        this.rowResourceId = textViewResourceId;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(rowResourceId, parent, false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        int id = Integer.parseInt(Ids[position]);
        String imageFile = Model.GetbyId(id).IconFile;

        textView.setText(Model.GetbyId(id).Name);
        // get input stream
        InputStream ims = null;
        try {
            ims = context.getAssets().open(imageFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // load image as Drawable
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
        // set image to ImageView
        imageView.setImageDrawable(d);
        return rowView;

    }

}
```

.7. Load model, find listview and assign adapter in the main activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Globals 
{

    ListView listView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Model.LoadModel();
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        String[] ids = new String[Model.Items.size()];
        for (int i= 0; i < ids.length; i++)
        {

            ids[i] = Integer.toString(i+1);
        }

        ItemAdapter adapter = new ItemAdapter(this,R.layout.row, ids);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }   

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

.Okay, so now that you hopefully understand what I have done, I can explain the problem. I would like to update the global variables in the listview based on data that I will be receiving over USB. However, I cannot seem to figure out how to do this. I tried the following code within the main activity but it did not update the data...

```
temperature = 5;
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

### Update

So I have created a new ArrayList with the new data that I want to display in the ListView. I then populate the ListView, set the ListView to the adapter and then call notifyDataSetChanged. However, my code still does not seem to update. Any advice is greatly welcomed!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

    public static int temperature;
    public static int humidity;
    public static int lpg;
    public static int alcohol;

    ListView listView;
    ListView listView1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Model.LoadModel();
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        String[] ids = new String[Model.Items.size()];
        for (int i= 0; i < ids.length; i++)
        {

            ids[i] = Integer.toString(i+1);
        } 

        ItemAdapter adapter = new ItemAdapter(this,R.layout.row, ids);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


        //Simulate updated data that will come from USB
        temperature = 1; humidity = 60; lpg = 5000; alcohol = 500;

        //Create new ArrayList with updated data
        ArrayList<Item> Items1;
        Items1 = new ArrayList<Item>();
        Items1.add(new Item(1, "temperature_icon.png", "Temperature/Humidity" + temperature + "°C / " + humidity + "%"));
        Items1.add(new Item(2, "gas_icon.png", "LPG" + lpg +" ppm"));
        Items1.add(new Item(3, "alcohol_icon.png", "Alcohol" + alcohol + " ppm"));
        //Populate ListView
        listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        String[] ids1 = new String[Items1.size()];
        for (int i= 0; i < ids1.length; i++)
        {

            ids1[i] = Integer.toString(i+1);
        }
        //Bind new ListView to Adapter
        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listView1.invalidateViews();


    }
```

### Update # 2

I have now both created a new listview to display the updated data, as well as created a new adapter to which I can attach the listview. However, when I call notifyDataSetChanged(); the new data is not displayed; I still see the original data.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

    public static int temperature;
    public static int humidity;
    public static int lpg;
    public static int alcohol;

    ListView listView;
    ListView listView_new;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Model.LoadModel();
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        String[] ids = new String[Model.Items.size()];
        for (int i= 0; i < ids.length; i++)
        {

            ids[i] = Integer.toString(i+1);
        } 

        ItemAdapter adapter = new ItemAdapter(this,R.layout.row, ids);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


        //--Simulate new data--//
        temperature = 1; humidity = 60; lpg = 5000; alcohol = 500;

        //Create new ArrayList with updated data
        ArrayList<Item> Items_new;
        Items_new = new ArrayList<Item>();
        Items_new.add(new Item(1, "temperature_icon.png", "Temperature/Humidity                  " + temperature + "°C / " + humidity + "%"));
        Items_new.add(new Item(2, "gas_icon.png", "LPG                                                   " + lpg +" ppm"));
        Items_new.add(new Item(3, "alcohol_icon.png", "Alcohol                                             " + alcohol + " ppm"));

        //Populate ListView
        listView_new = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        String[] ids_new = new String[Items_new.size()];
        for (int j= 0; j < ids_new.length; j++)
        {
            ids_new[j] = Integer.toString(j+1);
        }

        //Create new adapter
        ItemAdapter adapter_new = new ItemAdapter (this,R.layout.row, ids_new);
        //Bind new ListView to Adapter
        listView_new.setAdapter(adapter_new);
        //listView_new.invalidateViews();
        adapter_new.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your Main Activity updated code needs to be that complicated; I got this to work for me. It gave me a list with the updated global variable values...

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Model.LoadModel();
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    String[] ids = new String[Model.Items.size()];
    for (int i= 0; i < ids.length; i++)
    {

        ids[i] = Integer.toString(i+1);
    }

    ItemAdapter adapter = new ItemAdapter(this,R.layout.row, Model.Items);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    temperature = 1; humidity = 60; lpg = 5000; alcohol = 500;
    Model.LoadModel();
    ItemAdapter adapter2 = new ItemAdapter(this,R.layout.row, Model.Items);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter2);

}
```

Comment: I extended my MainActivity with my Model class and tried the code above but I keep running into errors. When I try to pass "Model.Items" as an argument in ItemAdapter I get the following error: The constructor ItemAdapter(MainActivity, int, ArrayList<Item>) is undefined

Comment: Okay I got it to work by changing `ItemAdapter adapter2 = new ItemAdapter(this,R.layout.row, Model.Items);` to `ItemAdapter adapter2 = new ItemAdapter(this,R.layout.row, ids);` I can now update the data. However, I have one more issue that maybe you could help me with. The reason that I was creating a new listview is that I wanted to be able to rearrange the order of the list based on the data that I will be getting. So, for example, if humidity does not change but alcohol does, then I wanted to be able to move alcohol to the top of the list. Any idea on how to get this to work? Thanks!

Comment: Glad you've gotten your list to update. As for sorting your list data, that should be a fun exercise for you. This wiki page links to some nice examples... [sorting algorithm-wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I don't actually want to sort the data, I just want to change the display order. That is why I created a new list (Update 2) so that if I want when I create the list I can manually change the order. I just want to swap the items in listview, but I cannot seem to figure out how to do this. I have looked at tutorials but they all seem to be for "drag and drop", whereas I just want to swap the rows automatically. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. I suppose upon updating the values, you could select the item you want to go to the top of the list and set it as the zeroth element and recreate the list.

Answer (score 0):

You feed data to a listview from an array through an adapter. To change data of a listview, you need to set new data to adapter and then call notifydatachanged on adapter.

Something like this:

```
mAdapter.setListData(mSubMenu1);
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: What would be the best way to do this since I already have an adapter that I am using to add images to the listview?

Comment: Everytime u get the new data over USB, update your arrayList, then set that arraylist to adapter using setListdata. And then call notifyDataSetChanged. In the example above, mSubMenu1 is the new array which replaces the old array in my case. This way I get my list updated.

Comment: So since I already have a custom adapter, do I need to add a textview in order to be able to display data in each row? I am slightly confused on how to display data in the rows.

Comment: From your code, I can see that u already have a textview and imageview for displaying text and an image as a listitem. For updateing them, you need to update the array or create new array and attach is again to your adapter.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. So once I create my new ArrayList how do I update the listview with this new data?

Comment: mAdapter.setListData(newArrayList);
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); ..   This will update your listview as adapter is feeding data to listview.

Comment: Okay thank you for that. I understand that this is the correct way to do it. However, do you know why the original way I was doing it wasn't working? Thanks

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you know why the way I was doing it originally wasn't working?

Comment: The way it works is, you have provided a set of data to adapter which updates the listview. Everytime getView() is called and the listview is updated. So, basically you have to update listview, you need to update adapter. So, to update adapter we are using "setListdata"

Comment: Moreover global data concept does not work with android between different files. So, only we use concepts like sharedPrefernces to save data at one place and use at other or pass them in intent.

Comment: Oh ok; I'm so used to C programming. I have one more quick question. Since I am using a custom arraylist that displays an image and a string, how would I modify this arraylist from my main activity in order to update the data? Thank you for all your help.

Comment: as you custom layout is inflated, so you can access both your textview and imageview in mainactivity. And it is possible to change image of imageview from code and change text of textview from code. You need to check relevent apis

Comment: I have been searching for an example of how to do this buy I am having trouble? Could you please point me in the right direction on how to do this? thank you

Comment: Okay I Believe I have made some progress. I create a new ArrayList with the updated data that I receive from USB. Then I populate the listView and then assign this listView to the adapter and then call notifyDataSetChanged. However, I still cannot seem to update the data. I have updated the original post to reflect my progress, as I cannot post the code in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Once you update your values, make a new list of updated objects and set a new adapter with the new list of updated items. You'll have to do this through an "onClick" method which you'll create.

**UPDATE:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
public static int temperature;
public static int humidity;
public static int lpg;
public static int alcohol;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    temperature = 4;
    humidity = 20;

    String item1 = "Temperature/Humidity" + temperature + "°C / " + humidity + "%";
    List myList = new ArrayList();
    myList.add(item1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    temperature = 10;
    humidity = 30;
    String item1 = "Temperature/Humidity" + temperature + "°C / " + humidity + "%";
    List myList = new ArrayList();
    myList.add(item1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Put the following into a LinearLayout with vertical orientation...

```
 <Button 
    android:id="@+id/updateList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Update List"
    android:onClick="onClick"/>
<ListView 
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: This is what I am having trouble with. How exactly do I go about creating this new list from within my main activity? Thanks

Comment: If you're planning on using a button click or something to make your new list with updated Item values, just create an onClick method in your main activity that creates the new list with updated values in the same way as you did in onCreate()...

Comment: I'm fairly new to Android programming so sorry if I am a bit slow. I think I understand how the listview and the adapter were originally declared and set up and everything. What I don't understand is how to modify the text in the list from within the main activity in order to display my updated data. Could you possible provide me with a code example or some sort of reference tutorial. Thank you very much

Comment: Okay I have made some progress. I create a new ArrayList with the updated data that I receive from USB. Then I populate the listView and then assign this listView to the adapter and then call notifyDataSetChanged. However, I still cannot seem to update the data. I have updated the original post to reflect my progress. I am not sure at all what is going on. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I added some code to my original answer to show how updating the list works. Try it out. It's very simplified; I extended 'ListActivity' to generate a simple list of string values (only one item in my example), not objects as you have, but the principle is the same. If you try out the code I've given, make sure to set up a simple linear layout in xml with a ListView and a button. The list view id should be "@android:id/list", as is standard practice with ListActivity.

Comment: Okay I will try this; however, I need to be able to update my list with objects not strings. Out of curiosity, do you have any ideas why my code above is not working? I create a new arraylist, populate the array list with my new objects containing the new data and then I attach that new list to the adapter and update the adapter with adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); Thanks for your help so far

Comment: You've created a new list, but are trying to set the previously created adapter to it; just create a new adapter and set it with the new list. You can see that's what I've done in my "onClick" method. If you do this in onCreate(), all you'll see is the updated list because the original list gets replaced by the new one almost instantly. I don't mind helping, but share the love and upvote the comments/answers that help you and select the answer that best helps you with the problem (even if not mine). I'll stick with this dialog as long as you have questions about it.

Comment: I sincerely appreciate your help so far. I have updated my code to create a new custom adapter that functions similarly to the old one and then I assign my new list to this adapter and then call notifyDataSetChanged(); Curiously, I still see the old data displayed. Am I missing something?

Comment: I also tried removing the old items from the first adapter and then adding the new ones but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: First, try extending MainActivity with your Model class (public class Model extends MainActivity), and define your global variables in the MainActivity as you have in your updated code. Second, check the new answer I've put up.